# How to adjust components in Java Swing Layouts?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout, flowlayoutpanel

I have been trying to make a Java Swing GUI in `Eclipse Window Builder`. After much of toil, I have been able to get to this. What I did was make a `JFrame`, add a `BorderLayout` to it. I added two panels in the `north` and `south` positions of this layout. I added a few buttons in the bottom panel.

*My question is from the top panel.* This panel has a `Flow Layout`, and has `two more panels`. The left panel has buttons which are at the right place. The right panel is itself not at the right place.

1. **I want the right panel to be aligned to the right side of the parent window** (and the left panel should stay on the left) - so ultimately there will be some space between the right and left panels. **That is both the right and the left panels should be right and left aligned) and there should be space between them, because I want 4 buttons to the left, and 2 buttons to the right side of my screen.**
2. In the right panel, the **two rightmost button among the two buttons should be right aligned**, and there should be **some space between both the buttons**.

I am providing the source code. I will be grateful if somebody can help/guide me to achieve what I want.

[image]

---

**SOURCE CODE:-**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ParentFrame extends JFrame {
    public ParentFrame() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(50, 50));

        JPanel parentPanel_bottom = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(parentPanel_bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JButton btnInstr = new JButton("1");
        parentPanel_bottom.add(btnInstr);
        JButton btnCourse = new JButton("2");
        parentPanel_bottom.add(btnCourse);
        JButton btnModule = new JButton("3");
        parentPanel_bottom.add(btnModule);
        JButton btnDays = new JButton("4");
        parentPanel_bottom.add(btnDays);
        JButton btnXtra = new JButton("5");
        parentPanel_bottom.add(btnXtra);

        JPanel parentPanel_top = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(parentPanel_top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        parentPanel_top.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));


        JPanel topleftpanel = new JPanel();
        parentPanel_top.add(topleftpanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JButton button = new JButton("1");
        topleftpanel.add(button);
        JButton button_1 = new JButton("2");
        topleftpanel.add(button_1);
        JButton button_2 = new JButton("3");
        topleftpanel.add(button_2);
        JButton button_3 = new JButton("4");
        topleftpanel.add(button_3);

        JPanel toprightpanel = new JPanel();
        parentPanel_top.add(toprightpanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        parentPanel_top.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
        JButton button_4 = new JButton("1");
        toprightpanel.add(button_4);
        JButton button_5 = new JButton("2");
        toprightpanel.add(button_5);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try with either `BoxLayout` or `GridBagLayuout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
JPanel parentPanel_top = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
...
JPanel topleftpanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
parentPanel_top.add(topleftpanel);    
...
JPanel toprightpanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 5, 5));
parentPanel_top.add(toprightpanel);
```

Note : remove extra `setLayout()` set for above `JPanel`s.

[image]

Comment: Something else happened here. I am uploading a screen shot

Comment: Look at my code `parentPanel_top.add(toprightpanel, BorderLayout.EAST);` remove `BorderLayout.EAST` because now its a `GridLayout`

Comment: Same for `parentPanel_top.add(topleftpanel, BorderLayout.WEST);`

Answer (score 0):

The layout you set to the `parentPanel_top` panel is flowLayout you cant just call the BorderLayout.WEST to specify it to the west.. BorderLayout can only use it not FlowLayout..

**Solution:**

change the layout to BorderLayout..

```
parentPanel_top.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Comment: I am sorry I am unable to comprehend what you just said. Do you mean to say that I should use border layout instead of flowlayout?